# Removing double punctuation when SI units with dots occur at the end of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, siunitx

I'm writing a document that uses a mix of SI and [atomic units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units). The latter are usually written in the slightly awkward notation

> p = 1 a.u.

with dots and all. (I know, it's not great, but what can I do?) Since I'm using SI units, I would like to use a cohesive approach to units throughout, via the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, which has the advantage of proper and easy styling of the atomic units. These can be incorporated into the SI package via a custom `\DeclareSIUnit` command, which works perfectly well:

```
\documentclass[aps,onecolumn,preprint,pra]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\au}{{a.u.}}

\begin{document}

The momentum is $p=\SI{1}{\au}$, so the energy is $E=\SI{0.5}{\au}$. 
The position is therefore unknown.

\end{document}
```

The problem is that at the end of a sentence you get double periods, one from the `a.u.` and one from the explicit period. This can be remedied by manually removing the latter, but it makes me liable to forget one if I move things around.

Is there an automatic way to make the `siunitx` unit `\au` to "eat" any period if it occurs immediately afterwards?

Comment: Si units are represented by symbols not abbreviations. As such they should not have decimal points in them: see http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/. There is no `au` unit in any case: you probably want for example 'a.u. of energy' which looks like `$E_{\mathrm{h}}$`. (This doesn't of course answer the technical question, hence being a comment.)

Comment: @JosephWright: Unfortunately, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units#Use_and_notation, using just `a.u.` in that case instead of `E_h` seems to be the common thing to do, ambiguity and incoherence with "proper" units notwithstanding.

Comment: @Jake Like I said, not an answer but a comment :-) At a technical level there is no look-ahead in `siunitx` and indeed it would be pretty tricky to work out a logic (you first need to know that the last unit ends with a period, then skip over any `$`, `\)`, _etc._ then look at the next char: not at all easy).

Comment: @Jake Also, and I'm sure you know this, Wikipedia isn't always right :-) The BIPM documentation, however, is _definitive_ on the rules.

Comment: @Joseph I know, which is why I hedged and apologized :). It's not great with consistency, but that's what people use, and anything else in my particular case would just be awkard. (For example, the momentum would be `$p=\sqrt{2E_\mathrm{H}}$` in your suggested notation.) Journals do use the dotted `a.u.`; see e.g. [this guidance from Phys. Rev. C](https://journals.aps.org/prc/info/infoC.html).

Comment: No, removing the explicit period manually does not solve the problem. The spacing becomes different (smaller), as Latex does not recognize the end of the sentence with just the dot from `a.u.`.

Comment: @Jost I'm aware of that but honestly I think it's not terrible. I would like to see a proper fix, however.

Comment: @E.P. I think this is a problem; after all, I'm using `siunitx` to get the spacing correct. If I have to break proper spacing to achieve literal correctness (i.e., avoid double dots), I could just revert back and use something like `$\text{a.u.}$` for atomic units.

Answer (score 13):

There's little hope of having a syntax like `\SI{10}{\au}`, because this would involve deep surgery in `siunitx`.

A syntax such as `\au{10}` seems to be the best choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\au}{m}
 {
  \SI{#1}{{a.u.}}
  \peek_charcode_remove:NT .
   {
    \mode_if_math:F { \spacefactor\sfcode`\.\scan_stop: }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The star is at \au{10} from Earth.
Stars can be farther than \au{1000}.
The preceding period is considered
end of sentence.


% retry to see that space factor is honored
\sfcode`\.=20000 \xspaceskip=30pt

The star is at \au{10} from Earth.
Stars can be much much farther than \au{1000}.
The preceding period is considered
end of sentence.

\end{document}
```

We typeset `\SI{10}{{a.u.}}` and then peek at the next token; if it is a period, it is removed, but the space factor is reset as if the period would be there.

In the example, the paragraph is repeated to make evident what periods affect the space factor, with a very exaggerated setting.

[image]

A variant that also checks whether `\au{...}` comes at the end of a math formula, but that requires you use `$`. The test could be also improved with a check for `\)`, which is left as an exercise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\au}{m}
 {
  \SI{#1}{{a.u.}}
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF .
   {
    \mode_if_math:F { \spacefactor\sfcode`\.\scan_stop: }
   }
   {
    \mode_if_math:T
     {
      \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT $
       {
        \group_insert_after:N \jost_check_period:
       }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jost_check_period:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NT .
   {
    \spacefactor\sfcode`\.\scan_stop:
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The star is at \au{10} from Earth.
Stars can be farther than \au{1000}.
The preceding period is considered
end of sentence.

This has the thing is math: $E=\au{10}$.

% retry to see that space factor is honored
\sfcode`\.=20000 \xspaceskip=30pt

The star is at \au{10} from Earth.
Stars can be much much farther than \au{1000}.
The preceding period is considered
end of sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, my opinion is that you should either avoid the symbol with the periods or leave two periods, which mean different things.

Comment: I like that `xspace` is avoided here. However, I see the same caveat that @LaRiFaRi's solution has, namely it fails to properly typeset something like `The energy is $E=\au{0.5}$.`. I know that peeking outside the equation is one of the major difficulties mentioned by @JosefWright. I would still like to see an attempt to solve this.

Comment: @Jost Here you are. But, as I added, you should leave the end of sentence period next to the symbol; actually I'd remove the periods from the symbol.

Comment: Your variant removes a space where it should remain: `10 a.u.from Earth.`. Concerning the general question of whether one should write two dots or only one: I actually prefer the double dot, but I won't mark my thesis...

Comment: @Jost Fixed. For what it's worth, you have my sympathy. `;-)` Is IAU authoritative? I guess so; look at https://www.iau.org/publications/proceedings_rules/units/ where “au” is recommended.

Comment: Not quite, the IAU fittingly talks about the astronomical length unit (`au`). This question is about atomic units (`a.u.`), which are on a totally different scale. But this mix-up explains, why your text is about stars and Earth being separated by a few picometers (`1 a.u. ~ 53 pm`).

Answer (score 8):

If it is feasible for you, you may want to introduce a new command for this. In my solution, you will not be able to write `\SI{123}{\au}`, but it will handle all possibilities.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\au}[1]{%
    \@ifnextchar{.}
    {\SI{#1}{{a.u}}}
    {\SI{#1}{{a.u.}}\ifmmode\else\@\xspace\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    In the middle \au{123} of a sentence. At the end of a sentence \au{123}. In inline $a\au{123}b$ and in a display equation \[a\au{123}b\]

    The momentum is $p=\au{1}$, so the energy is $E={}$\au{0.5}. % This is the only caveat here...
    The position is therefore unknown.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing a `%`, it doesn't matter here because `\@ifnextchar` ignores spaces, still, I would add the `%`.

Comment: I will edit now (since you added it in the wrong line :D it's needed after the third argument, between arguments TeX skips spaces); but I don't usually do it since, not long ago, an edit (obviously good in my opinion) wasn't well received.